# SED add a line after a text with backslash Character

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file called: options.conf
In that file are this lines:

```
  -queue_run \
  -rejected_header \
  -retry_defer \
  -skip_delivery \
```

Now i have made a SED bash .SH file (every thing works fine) expect 1 thing won't work :( and that is to add a line into the file..after `-skip_delivery \`

I want to add this line: `+arguments` (without blackslash so only text) after `-skip_delivery \`

So it will look like this:

```
      -queue_run \
      -rejected_header \
      -retry_defer \
      -skip_delivery \
      +arguments
```

I am trying to get this work for 2 hours now, can someone help me please?
I tried already this:

```
sed -i '/  -skip_delivery \/a \
+arguments' /root/options.conf
```

But no results :(

Comment: why don't you just use `echo "+arguments" >> options.conf` ?

Comment: Dude, Its not only that 4 lines into options.conf file.. Its a big  structured config file: http://files.directadmin.com/services/exim.conf - i just need to add a line into log_selector at the end of -skip_delivery! with SED !!! because i'm working on a SH script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just:

```
sed '/-skip_delivery/a \ \ +arguments' file
```

The mistake in your sed command was, the escaped slash which encloses regular expression `\/`.

Comment: Thansk Chaos !! This is working, you only forget to put the `i` option ;) May god bless people like you ;)

Answer (score 0):

the sed append syntax is like this:

```
sed '/PATTERN/ a\
    Line which you want to append' filename
```

there are two problems in your command:

- the backslash `\` need to be escaped. you don't escape it, so it terns the slash before command `a` into a literal char.
- In addition, you need to use option `-e` to specify the command to execute.

The fixed code would look like this:

```
sed  -i -e '/  -skip_delivery \\/ a\
+arguments' /root/options.conf
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer @oxnz, but your fixed code is not working for me .. in options.conf  `-skip_delivery \ ` sta ys there.. and underneath there i don't see : `-arguments` :(

Comment: you may want to loose your pattern a bit, cause I see there's two space before `-skip_delivery, Is this right? you may want to replace the pattern with `/\s*-skip_delivery\s*\\/`. `\s*` means match any space chars

Comment: Thanks, but this is working fine for me : `sed -i  '/-skip_delivery/a \ \ +arguments' file` may god bless you for ya help ;)